# Facebook GraphAPI unable to like

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Here is my code

http://www.facebook.com/241748079209258/posts/352844854766246?UID=241748079209258_352844854766246&AuthorID=241748079209258&PageID=241748079209258&PostID=352844854766246

if i simply open above link a page will opend and then type following link in browser i got error

https://graph.facebook.com/352844854766246/likes

But if i use bellow link

http://www.facebook.com/241748079209258/posts/343416792375719?UID=241748079209258_343416792375719_4237166&AuthorID=100003329558664&PageID=241748079209258&PostID=343416792375719&CommentID=4237166

And type following url

https://graph.facebook.com/343416792375719/likes

I got the result.

why am I getting an error in my first case?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but this might be what you're looking for:
https://graph.facebook.com/241748079209258_352844854766246/likes

Your first link points to a photo, and the other to a status update. To get information about the photo you have to prefix it with the owner's page ID or user ID.

Please note that you only have READ access to likes. You can not make anyone like something without having them click a Like button.